# Tripling an involution (Functional equation)

Tags: functional-equations

Here's a standard trick which is claimed by [Evan Chen](http://web.evanchen.cc) in one of his handouts: [Introduction to Functional Equations](http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf):

**Tripling an Involution:** *If you know something about $f(f(x))$, try applying it $f(f(f(x)))$ in different ways. For example, if we know that $f(f(x))=x+2$, then we obtain $$\boxed{f^3(x)=f(x+2)=f(x)+2}$$*

---

Now, I fail to understand how $f^3(x)\equiv f(x)+2$. May I get an explanation of how that transformation just took place.

Answer (score 3):

$$f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))=f(f(y))=y+2=f(x)+2$$ where y=f(x)